# tornado: how to add www if user doesn't type

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using the Tornado with python to build a web server. I want to allow users not to type `www`.

For example, if user types `example.com` to visit my web page, I want to add `www` for user. In other words, if user types `example.com` in his browser and type "Enter", a `www` will be inserted automatically in front of `example.com`.

This is my code for now:

```
application.add_handlers(r"^(www).*", [(r"/$", IndexHandler)])
```

With the code above, if user visits `www.example.com`, the class `IndexHandler` will get the request and render the index page (`self.render('/index.html')`).

Then I've tried like this:

```
application.add_handlers(r"^(example).*", [(r"/$", RedirectionHandler)])


class RedirectionHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('www.example.com')
```

Well, it doesn't work because `self.redirect` gives me `example.com/www.example.com`

Comment: why can't you append www. in the form input tag itself, using javascript. Why does user even has to enter 'www'. When the user starts typing use jquery to append www

Comment: Have you tried `self.redirect('http://www.example.com')` ?

Comment: @Goufalite   It works! Make an answer and do some explanation please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

`seft.redirect('http://www.example.com')`

In general in any language when you redirect plain text, the system thinks it's a relative url and tries to append/complete the url with the existing hostname in the already typed url (here `example.com`).

Putting `http(s)://` at the beginning tells that the address is absolute, so you rewrite all the address from scratch.